# Check if Observable is undefined

Tags: angular, angular7

On an Angular 7 application I have the following template:

```
<div *ngIf="avatarUrl$ | async;">
  <ng-container *ngIf="avatarUrl$ | async as avatarUrl">
    <img [src]="avatarUrl ? avatarUrl : 'avatar-default.png'">
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

The `avatarUrl$` is an observable as is obtained from a database through a service.

I want to display the IMG only after `avatarUrl$` has a value loaded.

However, sometimes that value obtained from the service is undefined.

In that case I need to display the default avatar, e.g: `avatar-default.png`.

The problem is that `avatar-default.png` is not displayed when `avatarUrl$` is undefined.

I think because of this condition that does not differentiate from the value not being loaded and being loaded but is undefined?

```
<div *ngIf="avatarUrl$ | async;">
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that with object of observable. It is usefull when you want the value `null`, `undefined` or `0` from your observable not to be blocked in the `*ngIf`

```
<div *ngIf="{url: avatarUrl$ | async} as data">
    <img [src]="data.url ? data.url : 'avatar-default.png'">
</div>
```

It's good to know, that you can have multiple observables in your object if you want:

```
<div *ngIf="{url: avatarUrl$ | async, picture: pictureUrl$ | async} as data">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Seems a bit redundant, you can do just this:

```
<div>
  <img [src]="(avatarUrl$ | async) || 'avatar-default.png'">
</div>
```

Or change your observable in your component:

```
readonly avatarUrl$ = this.getAvatarFromSomeWhere().pipe(
  startWith('avatar-default.png')
);

<div>
  <img [src]="avatarUrl$ | async">
</div>
```

Then you don't need to do any `||` and just keep the template simple. This way only works when you are sure the request will return an avatar eventually

Otherwise you can expand a bit on it using `map` which will make sure it will always return a value:

```
private readonly defaultAvatar = 'avatar-default.png';

readonly avatarUrl$ = this.getAvatarFromSomeWhere().pipe(
  map((avatar) => avatar || this.defaultAvatar),
  startWith(this.defaultAvatar)
);
```

**edit**

@C_Ogoo is right, I should have read better.

In the case you want it to only show after it has been loaded, you just need to change the observable like this:

```
readonly avatarUrl$ = this.getAvatarFromSomeWhere().pipe(
  map((avatar) => avatar || 'avatar-default.png')
);
```

and you can do the template like:

*template*

```
<div *ngIf="avatarUrl$ | async as avatarUrl">
  <img [src]="avatarUrl">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer, it covers everything that OP needs +1. `startWith` is the answer

Comment: I like this approach, though i don't think it covers the OP's use case. As this will always show the default first, and then later switch to the returned avatar if it exists. Whilst I think the OP only wants to show the default if there is no avatar

Answer (score 0):

First check value of Observable is undefined or not..

```
<ng-container *ngIf= avatarUrl$ === 'undefined' | async ; else loaded >
        <img [src]='avatar-default.png'>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loaded >
    <div *ngIf="avatarUrl$ | async;">
          <img [src]="avatarUrl">
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, it happened when an observable value passed to `ngFor` before it fired values.

```
//component.ts
this.data = Array<string> | Observable<Array<string>>; 

this.data=getData(); // <---- this.data here already has a value
// getData() returns Observable<Array<string>>

this.data.subscribe(result=>{
  this.data = result // <--- this.data value just changed witch introduces another issue
})
```

```
//template.html
<ng-container *ngIf="data;">
  <!-- 
     actually, data here has an observable value, so this template block will always executed
      it's initial value is observable, which is neither an iterable nor undefined
  --> 
  
 {{ data }} <-- error occurs here

</ng-container>
```

another issue introduced by this design pattern is that changing this.data value will make this template block to be evaluated again and the page will be loaded twice.

the correct design pattern here.

```
this.data: Array<string> | Observable<Array<string>>;
this.content: Array<string>; // <-- the initial value here is undefined which is correct

this.data = getData()
this.data.subscribe(result=>{
  this.content = result; // <-- use this.content instead of this.data
})
```

in your template file use `content` instead of `data`